# Vue & Webpack - make files unreadable after build

Tags: vue.js, webpack, build, vuejs2, webpack.config.js

I have set up a small project with Vue CLI and upload the built `dist folder` to my server. In the live version I can see all the .vue and .js files.

I wonder how Webpacks can make my files unreadable? I thought there is a standard build process that my source code is not viewable, or compiled in a way that makes it unreproducible.

Am I wrong? Do I need certain settings?

I don't use `webpack.config.js`.

Thank you

---

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.19.2",
  "core-js": "^3.6.4",
  "vue": "^2.6.11"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@vue/cli-service": "~4.2.0",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
...
}
```

Comment: Most likely the files are being minified but you can see the original source via the source maps. See https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#productionsourcemap

Comment: Thats the point I'm confused. I thought one positiv sideeffect from build with webpack is the unreproducable source code.

I will explore the documentation more deeply - thank you.

Comment: I don't think there's any mystery here, it's just source maps. There are plenty of resources explaining what source maps are if you aren't familiar with the concept. The link I provided explains how to turn them off with Vue CLI.

Comment: Keep in mind we are in Javascript-land and nothing is unreproducable - ever. It might not be easily human readable but this is just obfuscation. Please don't assume that the results of webpack are perfectly safe and therefore should contain sensitive data